# How can I add a 'test service' page to a WCF Webservice in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am building a Web service using WCF as a way to provide access to data within my VB.Net application.

When building web services hosted on IIS, there is a helpful test page as part of the service that allows the webservice to be invoked with parameters there and then. It's very helpful for testing.

Is there a way to configure a WCF hosted web service to provide the same sort of test interface, rather than the fairly unhelpul 'use svcutil' response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you have to build web pages form e.g. aspx to call the service and display the result, WCF service no more generates the UI for you anymore.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.. ah well.

Comment: How about WCFStorm (http://www.wcfstorm.com). It can handle even very complex data types.  Worth the look IMO

Answer (score 5):

Just fyi, you can also use, the [WcfTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) located at:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

which provides a lot of the functionality you are looking for

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this anyway, but beware that the otherwise really helpful WcfTestClient doesn't support DataSets as results.